# Webpack config node_modules outside dist

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to find the best solution for my project setup:

At the moment my folder structure look like this:

- dist
- node_modules
- src
- |- components
- |- styles
- |-- app.scss

My Webpack config works and compiles everything from 'src' to 'dist'.

1. I'm going to deploy content of 'dist' to the server so should I move node_modules inside 'dist' with webpack when I run build?
2. My app.scss reference dependencies from node_modules so if I move node_ modules inside 'dist' I will have to change paths in scss? How to do it?
3. The same issue with index.html and dynamic paths...

Is this the best practice?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the parts in your files where you required files from `node_modules` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile everything with Webpack, it imports the parts needed from the node_modules inside your compiled code. So the files outputted in your dist folder are "standalone". You don't need your node_modules anywhere except when you develop.
Regarding your app.scss, it will be transformed into CSS and node_modules `@imports` will be integrated inside your app.css.

Comment: Yes but let say I'm importing Bulma or Bootstrap and than FontAwsome some of them have referencies to the physical files. So I need to copy them over?

Comment: No, it will create a bundle of all the files necessary.
If you provide your webpack config I might be able to be more precise.